# future parser error in puppet

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I have below code

```
class dummy::eachtest{

$filename = [1,2,3]

each($filename) |$value| {
file {'/etc/dummy/manifests/${value}':
ensure => 'directory',
 }
}
```

I got below error when I compile

Could not match |$value| at /etc/dummy/manifests/eachtest.pp:5 on node
Got an update need to add future parser in config file

```
I added parser = future in puppet.conf under [master]
```

Now I am getting the below error when I compile eachtest.pp manifest

```
Use of 'import' has been discontinued in favor of a manifest directory
```

My puppet version is 3.7.3

Comment: Where's the import line that it's complaining about?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error says it all, really.

Without `parser=future` there is no `each` function.

With `parser=future`, you cannot rely on `import` anymore. Doing this is a pretty bad idea, anyway. It should be avoidable under all circumstances. If don't see how, please open a new question and detail your manifest layout.